# spring-integration-kafka: Annotation-driven handling of KafkaProducerMessageHandler result?

Tags: spring-integration, spring-kafka

Is there a way to achieve the behavior of the code below using annotation driven code?

```
@Bean
@ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "toKafka")
public MessageHandler handler() throws Exception {
    KafkaProducerMessageHandler<String, String> handler =
            new KafkaProducerMessageHandler<>(kafkaTemplate());
    handler.setTopicExpression(new LiteralExpression("someTopic"));
    handler.setMessageKeyExpression(new LiteralExpression("someKey"));
    handler.setSendSuccessChannel(success());
    handler.setSendFailureChannel(failure());
    return handler;
}

@Bean
public KafkaTemplate<String, String> kafkaTemplate() {
    return new KafkaTemplate<>(producerFactory());
}

@Bean
public ProducerFactory<String, String> producerFactory() {
    Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();
    props.put(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, this.brokerAddress);
    // set more properties
    return new DefaultKafkaProducerFactory<>(props);
}
```

Can I specify the send success/failure channels using Spring Integration annotations?

I'd like as much as possible to keep a consistent pattern of doing things (e.g., specifying the flow of messages) throughout my app, and I like the Spring Integration diagrams (e.g., of how channels are connected) IntelliJ automatically generates when you configure your Spring Integration app with XML or Java annotations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No; it is not possible, the success/failure channels have to be set explicitly when using Java configuration.

This configuration is specific to the Kafka handler and `@ServiceActivator` is a generic annotation for all types of message handler.